# XSLT Unexpected token beyond end of expression

Tags: excel, xml, xslt, ms-word

This is the source XML file converted from Excel document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Passiflora Cui</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Passiflora Cui</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2019-06-30T21:49:41Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2019-06-30T21:50:54Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>16940</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>27640</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>5580</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>3560</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="4" ss:ExpandedRowCount="5" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="65" ss:DefaultRowHeight="16">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="74"/>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field4</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field1_Data1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Field2_Data1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field3_Data1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field4_Data1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field1_Data2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Field2_Data2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field3_Data2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field4_Data2</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field1_Data3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Field2_Data3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field3_Data3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field4_Data3</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field1_Data4</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Field2_Data4</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field3_Data4</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field4_Data4</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>5</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>5</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

This is my XSLT, extracted the problem part from a larger one that converts Excel XML file to Word XML file, in which the `<a:ext></a:ext>` element causes the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:wb="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
    <xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes"/>

    <!-- Ignore all free text() nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match = "/wb:Workbook/wb:Worksheet/wb:Table">
        <pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
            <Result>
                <xsl:for-each select="wb:Row[position() > 1]">
                    <Test>
                        <Field1><xsl:value-of select = "wb:Cell[1]/wb:Data"/></Field1>
                        <Field2><xsl:value-of select = "wb:Cell[2]/wb:Data"/></Field2>
                        <Field3><xsl:value-of select = "wb:Cell[3]/wb:Data"/></Field3>
                        <Field4><xsl:value-of select = "wb:Cell[4]/wb:Data"/></Field4>
                    </Test>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Result>
            <!--The following a:ext element is just directly copied to the result, which causes the errors-->
            <a:ext uri="{05A4C25C-085E-4340-85A3-A5531E510DB2}">
                <thm15:themeFamily xmlns:thm15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/thememl/2012/main" name="Office Theme" id="{62F939B6-93AF-4DB8-9C6B-D6C7DFDC589F}" vid="{4A3C46E8-61CC-4603-A589-7422A47A8E4A}"/>
            </a:ext>
        </pkg:package>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<a:ext></a:ext>` element is copied from Word XML and just want to be copied directly to the result. However it reported error that "Unexpected token `<name>` beyond end of expression", the full error messages are as followed:

```
Severity: warning
Description: Error in expression 05A4C25C-085E-4340-85A3-A5531E510DB2: Unexpected token <name> beyond end of expression
Start location: 22:0

Severity: warning
Description: Error in expression 62F939B6-93AF-4DB8-9C6B-D6C7DFDC589F: Unexpected token <name> beyond end of expression
Start location: 23:0

Severity: warning
Description: Error in expression 4A3C46E8-61CC-4603-A589-7422A47A8E4A: Unexpected token <name> beyond end of expression
Start location: 23:0
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curly braces in attributes indicate that the contents are to be treated as XPATH expressions to be evaluated.  To get what you want you need to double the braces to escape them:

```
        <a:ext uri="{{05A4C25C-085E-4340-85A3-A5531E510DB2}}">
            <thm15:themeFamily 
                xmlns:thm15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/thememl/2012/main" 
                name="Office Theme" 
                id="{{62F939B6-93AF-4DB8-9C6B-D6C7DFDC589F}}" 
                vid="{{4A3C46E8-61CC-4603-A589-7422A47A8E4A}}"/>
        </a:ext>
```